# How to prevent overflow when converting varbinary to int

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following code gives me this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

```
select CONCAT(
    round( convert(varbinary, newid()) * 256, 0 ), '.',
    round( convert(varbinary, newid()) * 256, 0 ), '.',
    round( convert(varbinary, newid()) * 256, 0 ), '.',
    round( convert(varbinary, newid()) * 256, 0 )) SenderIP
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: Very good question.

Comment: `NewId()` returns a [`uniqueidentifier`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), a 16-byte value. You `convert` that to a `VarBinary(30)`, then attempt to multiply it by `256`. That forces an implicit conversion to `int` which truncates the value. `* 256` overflows. Aside: The best practice is to always supply a length for `var` types. [`Cast` and `Convert`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) default to `30`, otherwise the default length is `1`.

Comment: `Cast( Cast( NewId() as VarBinary(30) ) as Int ) & 0xFF` will give you non-negative values and, if repeated in a single query, return a different value for each expression.